# How to convert a '\' path to '\\'

Tags: python-3.x, path, subprocess

I'm coding a software in python and I'm trying to convert a windows path with `\` like `C:\Program Files\KiCad\7.0\bin` to a path with `\\` `C:\\Program Files\\KiCad\\7.0\\bin` so that it will be recognized as a path by python in send in a subprocess. Run command.

I tried Path () from pathlib; OS. Path. Normpath () but it doesn't work...

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the significance of ``\`` versus ``\\`` in path strings and their representations. The path separator in Windows is a single backslash (``\``). A double back slash only comes up in contexts where a single backslash has a different preexisting meaning (e.g., as an escape sequence) and where it can be escaped by preceding it with another backslash. The actual path you want is just `Path(r"C:\Program Files\KiCad\7.0\bin")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below function takes a path as parameter and prints all filenames with absolute path with double `\\`. It's pretty simple.

```
def get_absolutePath_for_all_file(path):
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        abs_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
        abs_path = abs_path.replace('\\','\\\\')
        print(abs_path)

path = r'C:\Users\mdmsarke\Desktop\MS_Data\Developer\GES_Survey\FY_22_23'
get_absolutePath_for_all_file(path)
```

Output:

```
C:\\Users\\mdmsarke\\Desktop\\MS_Data\\Developer\\GES_Survey\\FY_22_23\\future_contact_information
C:\\Users\\mdmsarke\\Desktop\\MS_Data\\Developer\\GES_Survey\\FY_22_23\\ges_raw_data_choice_text_6_27_23.csv
C:\\Users\\mdmsarke\\Desktop\\MS_Data\\Developer\\GES_Survey\\FY_22_23\\ges_raw_data_choice_text_6_27_23_for_upload.csv
C:\\Users\\mdmsarke\\Desktop\\MS_Data\\Developer\\GES_Survey\\FY_22_23\\ges_raw_data_choice_text_fall_2022.csv
C:\\Users\\mdmsarke\\Desktop\\MS_Data\\Developer\\GES_Survey\\FY_22_23\\ges_raw_data_choice_text_fall_2022_for_upload.csv
C:\\Users\\mdmsarke\\Desktop\\MS_Data\\Developer\\GES_Survey\\FY_22_23\\ges_raw_data_numerical_6_27_23.csv
```

Comment: Perfect, you solved my problem, thank's a lot for your help.